# Can't figure out why the program will not run properly

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input

I have been trying to get this program to work which is supposed to continue to take input from a user until -1 is entered and compute the sum.
The problem is as follows:
 Design and implement a Java program (name it 
InputSum
) that prompts the user to 
enter a positive integer number. The program should ac
cept integers until the user enters the value -1 
(negative one). After the user enters -1, the program s
hould display the entered numbers followed by their sum 
as shown below. Notice that -1 is not part of the output. 
Make sure the program 
validates each entered number before proc
essing it as the user may enter negative 
numbers other than the sentential value -1
.
Design your program such that it
 allows the user to re-run the 
program with a different set of inputs in the same run as shown above.
 Document your code, and organize and 
space out your outputs as shown above.

Here is my code:

```
/* Class:        CS1301
* Section:       9:30
* Term:          Fall 2015
* Name:          Matthew Woolridge
* Instructor:    Mr. Robert Thorsen
* Assignment:    Assignment 6
* Program:       1
* ProgramName:   InputSum
* Purpose:       The program prompts the user to input numbers until -1 is entered and calculates the sum
* Operation:     The information is statically instantiated in the code and
*                the data is output to the screen.
* Input(s):      The input is the numbers
* Output(s):     The output will be the sum of the numbers
* Methodology:   The program will use loops to determine if numbers or still to be entered or if -1 was entered
*
*/

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class InputSum
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

      /******************************************************************************
      *                          Declarations Section                               *
      ******************************************************************************/
      /****************************CONSTANTS********************************/
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Initializes scanner

      int n = 1;
      int [] num = new int[n]; //Creates array for input numbers
      int i;
      int sum=0;

      /******************************************************************************
      *                             Inputs Section                                  *
      ******************************************************************************/

      System.out.print("Please input integers, note that -1 ends the submissions: "); //Prompts the user for input

     /****************************variables********************************/
     //***************************Calculations in processing************************//
     /******************************************************************************
      *                             Processing Section                            *
      ******************************************************************************/
      for(i=0; i<num.length; i++)
      {
         num[i] = scan.nextInt(); //Continues to read numbers and add them to the sum
         n = n + 1; //Adds to the array maximum
         sum = sum + num[i]; //Calculates the sum
         if (num[i] == -1){
            break;
         }
      }
      System.out.print("The numbers entered are: " + num[i]);
      System.out.print("\nThe sum of the numbers is: " + sum);

      /******************************************************************************
       *                              Outputs Section                                *
       ******************************************************************************/
       //***************Output is in the processing**************************//
   }
}
```

The problem is, the program keeps getting hung up on the line where it is supposed to print the sum. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Your program is hunging up because your array size is '1' so it can only accept values for `num[0]`.

Comment: As you don't know how many values are entered by the user using an array is a bad choice. Use some data structure that expands as required. E.g. an ArrayList should fit your needs.

Comment: How should I go about using an arraylist, I haven't had to use it that often to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a List to store the numbers and an infinite loop to keep receiving inputs from the user. Also you should check the stop condition before starting to process the numbers (as your question mentions that -1 is not part of the output). Here is an illustration

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class InputSum
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

      /******************************************************************************
      *                          Declarations Section                               *
      ******************************************************************************/
      /****************************CONSTANTS********************************/
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Initializes scanner
      int number; //Declare a variable that will hold the temporal value that is read on the input stream      
      int sum=0;

      // Use a List 
      List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      /******************************************************************************
      *                             Inputs Section                                  *
      ******************************************************************************/

      System.out.print("Please input integers, note that -1 ends the submissions: "); //Prompts the user for input

     /****************************variables********************************/
     //***************************Calculations in processing************************//
     /******************************************************************************
      *                             Processing Section                            *
      ******************************************************************************/
      // use an infinite loop
      for(; ; )
      {


         // You should normally do this check when you enter the loop
         // so that -1 which is a stop token should not be added to the list
         // and not taken into account in the sum


         number = scan.nextInt(); //Continues to read numbers and add them to the sum
         if (number == -1){
              break;
         }

         // You could write numbers.add(number) which would be
         // Java's autoboxing feature, but this is what would really take place
         numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
         sum += number; //Calculates the sum


      }
      System.out.print("The numbers entered are: " + numbers);
      System.out.print("\nThe sum of the numbers is: " + sum);

      /******************************************************************************
       *                              Outputs Section                                *
       ******************************************************************************/
       //***************Output is in the processing**************************//
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help and thank you alainlompo for the example of the list! :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using arrays(because it limits your number of inputs), you could use a temporary variable which would calculate value of the sum. Such as shown below:

```
int sum=0;
int num=0;
while(num != -1) {
    sum = sum + num;
    num = scan.nextInt(); //note that the variables can be reused
}
```